# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I am trying to setup the multinode cluster of Hbase. When i do the jps on slave i get

```
5780 Jps
5558 HQuorumPeer
5684 HRegionServer
1963 DataNode
2093 TaskTracker
```

similarly on master i get

```
4254 SecondaryNameNode
15226 Jps
14982 HMaster
3907 NameNode
14921 HQuorumPeer
4340 JobTracker
```

EVerything is runnnig properly. But when i try to create table on hbase shell. It gives an error

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
```

regionserver log of my slave(where region server is running):

```
2013-06-11 13:09:53,119 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Attempting connect to Master server at localhost,60000,137093$
2013-06-11 13:10:53,190 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Unable to connect to master. Retrying. Error was:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: localhost/127.0.0.1:60000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
        at $Proxy8.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getMaster(HRegionServer.java:2037)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:744)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-06-11 13:10:53,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Attempting connect to Master server at localhost,60000,137093$
```

FYI, i have also took care of /etc/hosts file on both master and slave.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       naresh-PC
```

I again did changes in /etc/hosts file 127.0.1.1 to naresh-PC. But still getting this error

```
2013-06-11 14:51:17,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Attempting connect to Master server at naresh-pc,60000,137094$
2013-06-11 14:52:17,817 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Unable to connect to master. Retrying. Error was:
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: naresh-pc
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.<init>(HBaseClient.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.createConnection(HBaseClient.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
        at $Proxy8.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getMaster(HRegionServer.java:2037)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:744)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Also, i am being able to do password-less ssh from master to slave and slave to master.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try clearing all the states in Zookeeper.

- **Stop Zookeeper**
- **Wipe the Zookeeper data directory**
- **Start Zookeeper**

I was getting the same issue and followed this approach and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please explain how to perform these steps on Ubuntu. Can you list the commands that we need to follow.

Comment: Ran into this today and wiping the zk data directory also worked for me.  Nishu, your hbase-site.xml file should have a hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir property that tells where this path is.  Just make sure hbase is down before clearing it.

Comment: It is enough just to delete `/hbase` znode in ZooKeeper via zkCli.sh with command `rmr /hbase`. No need to delete whole ZooKeeper directory. Be sure HBase Masters are not running during znode deletion.

Comment: On more recent versions of ZooKeeper, the `rmr` command has been removed, use `deleteall` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the configuration on the slave node to point at the master. It is currently pointing to localhost and not connecting to the actual master:

> "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$FailedServerException: This
>   server is in the failed servers list: localhost/127.0.0.1:60000 at "

Comment: well, i did give master's ip but still get the same problem. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: master:60000 at

Comment: After setting `<property> <name>hbase.master</name> <value>ip-hmaster:60000</value> </property>` in `/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` on all slave nodes the issue was solved. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hosting my own cluster inside Docker. Here's what worked in my case. I grepped the HBase log file for errors and found "Master passed us a different hostname to use"

```
`[root@docker-iop bin]# grep ERROR /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-regionserver-bi-mgmt01.local.log
2016-10-06 00:05:29,816 ERROR [regionserver/bi-mgmt01.local/111.11.2.3:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Master passed us a different hostname to use; was=my-host-name, but now=111.22.33.444'
```

I mapped my-host-name to 111.22.333.444 in my hosts file, restarted HBase and it worked.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3431, https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7099/how-to-avoid-hbase-services-to-bind-on-multi-hosts, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-12954, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-18226 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21986077

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with a fully distributed hbase  cluster with the configuration below.

1. Master Node (Node-A)
2. Backup Masters ($HBASE_HOME/conf/backup-masters) (Node-B & Node-C)
3. 3 Replication servers (Node-A, Node-B & Node-C)

RCA:
The backup-masters  nodes were  attempted to be started when the cluster started.

Solution 
I removed the backup masters by making $HBASE_HOME/conf/backup-masters empty in all hbase nodes.

So I had a cluster running without backup masters.

I wonder if the master node and master  **nodes** must not also function as regionservers? The HBase documentation says otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and could not find anything, it turns out I was copy pasting from the Hbase documentation  (https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#shell_exercises). I believe some character in there may be creating the error, so try to manually enter:

`create 'test', 'cf'`

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue. Solution is to

- stop Hbase
- log to zookeeper-client as root
- execute command rmr /hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server
- start Hbase

We stop/start Hbase through Ambari UI, delete /hbase... through server bash shell.

```sh
[root@s1 ~]# zookeeper-client
Connecting to localhost:2181
.......
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] rmr /hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I use docker/docker-compose to set up my distributed hbase, after I make changes, I can not create table in hbase shell.

I `docker rm` all the related images, and rebuild them. It works. Also, simply rebuilding the images doesn't work...