# wiping out the Zookeeper data directory

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am very new to Hadoop/Hbase and zookeeper.
I am facing following exception while running `create table` command in `hbase shell`.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
```

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038957/org-apache-hadoop-hbase-pleaseholdexception-master-is-initializing) question it is mentioned that i need to follow these steps:

```
1. Stop Zookeeper  
2. Wipe the Zookeeper data directory  
3. Restart it
```

To resolve this issue.

Can someone please explain how to perform these steps in Ubuntu.
Any Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is this a pseudo-distributed HBase environment?

Comment: The error `PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing` can be due to a number of reasons. Have you looked in the HBase UI? Typically this is located at `http://localhost:60010/master-status` or similarly on the machine you are running the master.

Can you post the logs from your HBase master? Possibly under /var/log/hbase/?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> /zookeeperHome/conf/zoo.cfg: file will have data directroy details
>
> tickTime=2000
> dataDir=/var/zookeeper
> clientPort=2181

see [this](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the data directory is /tmp/zookeeper. Otherwise check zoo.cfg file. Check for property dataDir and clean up corresponding direcrory.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but on my Ubuntu i can't find "/tmp/zookeeper" or "zoo.cfg" file either. from one of the conf file of hbase i found that data dir is something "/opt/hbase-data/zookeeper/" but there are only tow folders in this dir "myid" and "version-2" are these the folders that i need to cleanup?

Comment: Ok. just clean up that folder

Comment: So i need to delete "myid" and "version-2" folder and run hadoop and hbase again?

Comment: i deleted both of these file and dir but problem is still same. still getting same errors.

Comment: You need the myid file, that contains an integer that uniquely identifies your zookeeper node. Deleting version-2 was all you needed.

Comment: Noticed a Ubuntu "apt-get install zookeeperd" installation default location at ./var/lib/zookeeper/myid with another one in ./etc/zookeeper/conf_example/myid, wonder which config has these referred