# Cannot create table in hbase shell : org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hbase-shell

I am trying to create a table in hbase shell using the command

**hbaseshell> create 'person', 'info'**

The command does not executes successfully and throws an error as below:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:2829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:2085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:336)

For usage try 'help "create"'
```

I searched online and found some answers. But the answers are not very clear. It just states to clear off -Wipe the Zookeeper data directory- .

But where is the data directory ? and how can I access it. Can someone please guide the steps needed?

```
mac@AS-MAC-0061 3.7.0_1 % jps
8417 DataNode
8851 NodeManager
9411 Launcher
1204 
8311 NameNode
14873 HMaster
8554 SecondaryNameNode
14682 QuorumPeerMain
8748 ResourceManager
15262 Jps
```

Attaching reference of answer I found but could not follow the directions.

[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038957/org-apache-hadoop-hbase-pleaseholdexception-master-is-initializing)

[wiping out the Zookeeper data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982919/wiping-out-the-zookeeper-data-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by deleting the directory : version-2 from the path /opt/homebrew/var/zookeeper/zookeeper_0.

The path can be found in the value of property : hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir mentioned in the hbase-site.xml

Works fine now !